# CheckMark Validation for Form

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

Implemented Register form by using Angular 4. Validating the input forms by using alert danger when the fields are empty.

Please advice how to validate those input form fields eg. username ,password....
by using check mark beside the input form.is validate means correct symbol not validate means x symbol.. Currently i am using html typescript and angular 4.

Thanks..

Comment: What you are trying to do is validate the form and based on that show a tick or a x . Am I right?

Comment: Yes you r correct . please advice how we can do

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

import { UserService } from './shared/user.service';
import { IUser, IUserAuth, IUserFeatures } from './shared/user.moldes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
/**
 * Class representing the LoginComponent.
 */
export class LoginComponent {
  public userForm: FormGroup;

  public username: string;
  public password: string;
  public submitted: boolean;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.buildForm();
  }

  /**
   * Triggers when the user click on the login button.
   */
  public onSubmit(): void {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (!this.userForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
    const user: IUser = {
      email: this.userForm.controls.username.value,
      password: Md5.hashStr(this.userForm.controls.password.value),
    };
    this.userService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(() => {
      // 
    });
  }

  /**
   * Builds the user login form.
   */
  private buildForm(): void {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: [null,[Validators.required],
      password: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

In the template.html

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate class="form-wrapper">

    <div class="form-group block"
         [ngClass]="{'has-error': submitted && (userForm.controls.username.errors)}">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="username">
      <p>
        <span *ngIf="submitted && userForm.controls.username.errors?.required">Username is required</span>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group block"
         [ngClass]="{'has-error': submitted && (userForm.controls.password.errors)}">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
      <p *ngIf="submitted && userForm.controls.password.errors?.required">Password is required</p>
    </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
      <div>
        <div *ngIf="submitted && userForm.valid">Tick</div>
        <div *ngIf="submitted && !userForm.valid">X</div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Based on **userForm.valid** you can show hide a icon. Hope this helps.

```
   <div>
       <div *ngIf="submitted && userForm.valid">Tick</div>
       <div *ngIf="submitted && !userForm.valid">X</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Do you get errors? What you have to do is display a div according to the valid status of your login form. Check the last div in the answer

Comment: Please send the example once

Comment: `*ngIf` Instead of `*ngIF`